# DataTable's sorting arrows not appearing (getting 404 in browser)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

I'm using DataTables on a C# project and the header's sorting arrows aren't appearing---in fact, in the console I'm getting a `404` error.

So I created a local `/images` folder (which is what the default DataTables png url was pointing to) but the `404` error is still coming back.

I tried tinkering around with the file paths under the `min.js` file but to no effect. Am I changing the path names correctly or is there something else that's causing the `404?`

A few things to note:

- I know very little about C#
- I'm working on this with Visual Studio 2019 and I'm still trying to get the hang of the layout

---

#### Solution Explorer

```
/ Content
  / images
     // sort_asc.png
  // jquery.dataTables.min.css (same level as /images)
```

#### dataTables.min.css snippet

```
.sorting_asc{background-image:url("images/sort_asc.png")} // not working

.sorting_desc{background-image:url("../images/sort_desc.png")} // original (how the file came)
```

#### BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/jquery.dataTables.min.css",
    "~/Content/fontawesome-5.9.0.css"
));
```

#### Console:

```
GET http://localhost:xxxxx/images/sort_asc.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Hey, check that you're referencing the path correctly for your image (including capitalisation)? (See how to properly reference it here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Also, in VS1029 for the folder that contains your image, right click the folder & select 'Open in Folder'. Double check that the image you're referencing is actually in this folder? NOTE: To add an image to a solution, it's safer to right click the folder > Add > Existing Item > (select  image), rather than plonking the image in the right folder.. if you do not 'add' it this way - it won't get checked in if you're using TFS (source control)!

Comment: Try with a slash at the front: `.sorting_asc { background-image:url("/images/sort_asc.png")}` or use a cdn.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing path in this way:

```
"~/Images/sort_desc.png"
```

Comment: Hi @cebilon123, is that under the min.css file or in `BundleConfig`?

Comment: Under dataTables.min.css.

Comment: Nope :( I'll tinker with it a bit more

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do some reading on how [paths work in HTML and CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#A_quick_primer_on_URLs_and_paths).

Given the structure you have provided us

```
.sorting_asc{background-image:url("/Content/images/sort_asc.png")}
```

This is a root relative URL.

Also note from your BundleConfig you have `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")`. This will serve your CSS bundle from `http://yoursite.com/Content/css/bundledCSS.css` and all paths will need to be changed accordingly even if the physical files are in the *content* directory. This is another reason why root relative urls are a good idea, the images are then independent of the location of the CSS file.